# Show that $(\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-2})/(\log n)\longrightarrow 1$ as $n\longrightarrow\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

As the title of this post, how could I show

> $$\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-2}}{\log n}\longrightarrow 1\ \text{as}\ n\longrightarrow\infty.$$

My attempt is the following:

To make $$\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-2}}{\log n}\longrightarrow 1,$$ equivalently we can show that as $n\rightarrow\infty$, we have $$1\leq\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-2}}{\log n}\leq 1,$$  which is the same as $$1\leq\dfrac{\log n}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-2}}\leq 1,$$ so that we want to show firstly, we have $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-2}\leq\log n\leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-2},$$ and $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-2}\longrightarrow 1\ \text{as}\ n\longrightarrow\infty.$$

However, I am not able to show neither of them...

Am I heading to a wrong direction?

Thank you!

**Edit 1:**

This edit follows the proof from "user284331"

Since $x\mapsto\dfrac{1}{x}$ is decreasing, we have $$\sum_{k=2}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k}\leq\int_{1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{t}dt\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k}.$$

Thus, by noting that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}<\infty$ and $\int_{1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{t}=\log (n)$, we have 
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}}{\log n}&\geq\dfrac{\int_{1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{t}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}}{\log n}\\
&=\dfrac{\log(n)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}}{\log n}\\
&=1-\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}}{\log n}\longrightarrow 1,
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}}{\log n}&=\dfrac{1+\sum_{k=2}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}}{\log n}\\
&\leq \dfrac{1+\int_{1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{t}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}}{\log n}\\
&=\dfrac{1+\log(n)}{\log(n)}-\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}}{\log n}\longrightarrow 1.
\end{align*}

Comment: In general, you can't have $1 \le A_n \le 1$ unless $A_n = 1$ for all $n$. So $1 \le A_n \le 1$ is a much stronger condition than $A_n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$. 

Anyway, do you know the [Stolz-Cesàro Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 No I did not know it before. how could I use this Theorem?

Comment: I like user284331's answer better. But if you can first show that $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{n^{-1}-n^{-2}}{\log(n) - \log(n-1)} = 1$ (which can be done with Taylor series / L'Hopital), you can then apply the Stolz-Cesàro Theorem to get that your desired limit is $1$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 okay. Definitely try it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\int_{1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{t}dt\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k}\\
\sum_{k=2}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k}\leq\int_{1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{t}dt
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}<\infty.
\end{align*}

So
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}}{\log n}&\geq\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_{1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{t}dt-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}}{\log n}\\
&=1-\dfrac{1}{\log n}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}\\
&\rightarrow 1.
\end{align*}

On the other hand,
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}}{\log n}&\leq\dfrac{1+\displaystyle\int_{1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{t}dt-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}}{\log n}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\log n}+1-\dfrac{1}{\log n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^{2}}\\
&\rightarrow 1,
\end{align*}
so the result follows by Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: Could you add more details?

Comment: I have added the details.

Comment: WOW. Thank you so much!

Comment: I checked your first claim. Should that be $\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k}\leq\int_{1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{t}dt\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k}?$ I don't think the inequality you gave is correct, since $t\mapsto\dfrac{1}{t}$ is decreasing, drawing a graph would yield.

Comment: I will edit my post to follow your argument.

Comment: Wait a minute, I will check carefully, but the main point is that, the integral of $1/t$ over $(1,\infty)$ is comparable to the sum of harmonic sequence.

Comment: Yes, your main point is exactly what inspired me immediately.

Comment: I think now it is correct.

Comment: Yes now it is correct. I've also edited my post, which is equivalent to your solution.

Comment: Thank you so much by the way :)

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k^2}=\zeta(2)$ is convergent, so its partial sums do not contribute to the value of the limit.
On the other hand the harmonic series is divergent, and by Cesàro-Stolz
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{H_{n}}{\log(n)}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{H_{n+1}-H_n}{\log(n+1)-\log(n)}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n+1}}{-\log\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)}=1. $$

Comment: WOW. thank you so much!